# Find department with maximum number of employees in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these two tables and I need to find the department name with maximum number of employees.

The other solutions were not for Oracle, so I'm posting this question. Also, it would be really helpful if the query can be explained thoroughly as I'm finding it hard to visualise it.

```
EMPLOYEE

EMPNO EMPNAME MANAGER SALARY DEPT_NO
1     Puja    6       30000  2
2     Purabi  1       15000  3
3     Barun   6       23000  2
4     Sudha   1       20000  1
5     Amal    2       20000  1
6     Rakesh  3       30000  4

DEPARTMENT

Dept_No Dept_Name  Location
1       Production LaneA
2       Marketing  LaneB
3       Sales      LaneC
4       HR         LaneD
```

So far I could manage getting the highest number of employees. So I was thinking if somehow I can write another sub-query where I count the employees in the departments again and compare them to the max_num_emp that I calculated in the first query.

This is the query which retrieves the maximum number of employees. It does not return the dept_no.

```
select count(dept_no)
from employee
group by dept_no
order by count(dept_no) desc
fetch first row only;
```

Expected output

```
DEPT_NAME
Production
Marketing
```

I can also add the dept_no column in the query, then I will have to somehow find out how to get the max and that was somehow giving me errors because the query was violating some rules. I had actually tried doing max(*above query*).

So I thought of just getting the maximum employee count and then determine all departments which have those many employees and display their name.

Comment: What have you tried?  Perhaps you have a query that gets the number of employees per department, for instance.

Comment: I've added it. Please check the edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have used `FETCH..FIRST` syntax using `WITH TIES` instead of `ONLY`.

```
SELECT d.dept_name
  FROM department d 
   JOIN employee e ON d.dept_no = e.dept_no
GROUP BY d.dept_name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) 
DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES ;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=55690e36bfbdd3a20c21de86779588d6)

Comment: This is such a simpler solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You have a working query which you need to join to the table `department`:

```
select d.Dept_Name   
from department d inner join (
  select dept_no
  from employee
  group by dept_no
  order by count(*) desc
  fetch first row only
) t
on t.dept_no = d.dept_no
```

Edit
Try this (I cannot try it):

```
select d.dept_name 
from department d inner join (
  select x.dept_no from (
    select dept_no, rank() over (order by count(*) desc) rn
    from employee
    group by dept_no
    order by count(dept_no) desc
  ) x
  where x.rn = 1
) t
on t.dept_no = d.dept_no
```

Comment: Hi, the query works perfectly, but how do I display just the dept_name column? I need just one column in the output. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, it is showing just dept_name now, but there are 2 departments which have maximum employees. It's showing just one for now.

Comment: This is what `fetch first row only` in your code does.

Comment: You can check why I added that clause in my query at the end of the question. I've clearly explained that it was because I couldn't get the `max()` function working.

Comment: It only displays Production.

Comment: I removed `fetch first row only` now. Try again

Comment: It's now working. Thanks a lot! It'll take me some time to understand it though. Anyway accepted your answer.

Comment: Fine if it worked. Check these: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions123.htm and https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/rank.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are not looking for duplicates, then:

```
select d.dept_name, count(*)
from department d join
     employee e
     on d.dept_no = e.dept_no
group by d.dept_no, d.dept_name
order by count(dept_no) desc
fetch first row only;
```

Comment: I need all department names which have the maximum employee count.